# Reading type`s property XMLName attribute value

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

Im working on my own MarshalXML function to get required output format for an input object, but cant seem to find a proper way of giving tags a proper names.

Let say i have:

```
type RootElement struct{
XMLName xml.Name `xml:"hello"`
world ChildElement `xml:"world"`
}
```

And a child element:

```
type ChildElement struct{
Value string
}
```

Then Encode method in MarshalXML for RootElement would give me:

```
<RootElement>
<ChildElement>
...
</ChildElement>
</RootElement>
```

Instead of that id have to create my own callset of EncodeToken methods in order to put there proper tag names, but even here i have to specify xml.Name as a constant string value even though i already have it defined in the model structs.

Is there some way to get 'hello' and 'world' tag names inside XMLMarshal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the RootElement name didn't work, but for the ChildElement, you have to put the tag `xml:",chardata"`, so the Value is detected as the ChildElement's value and not a node.

http://play.golang.org/p/pg2vhD8wMf

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type RootElement struct{
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"hello"`
    World ChildElement `xml:"world",`
}

type ChildElement struct{
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {
    r := RootElement{World: ChildElement{Value: "child value"}}
    m, err := xml.MarshalIndent(r, "", "  ")
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", m)
    }
}
```